# Akka Logging outside Actor

Tags: scala, logging, akka

I have an Akka Actor that makes a call to `MyObject.foo()`. `MyObject` is not an Actor. How do I setup Logging in it?  With an Actor it's simple, because I can just mixin ActorLogging. In MyObject, I don't have access to context.system. Do I create an `akka.event.Logging` with AkkaSystem() and then what for the LogSource implicit?

Comment: Have you've read this? : http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/logging.html

Comment: @ViktorKlang yep.  It doesn't seem to address my question, though, nor does it describe why the Akka event logger is need (as opposed to just using SLF4J directly within the Actor).

Comment: Because you can make any logging backend asynchronous since the logging is done via an actor.

Comment: @ViktorKlang why wouldn't you just implement the SLF4J API with an Akka async delegating backend? Instead, the Akka logging API does weird stuff like reversing the order of exception and message, and not supporting exceptions for log.warning.

Comment: Wouldn't have helped, someone else would complain we didn't use the Java Logging API (someone already did).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Actually I would redirect Akka logging to [slf4j](/questions/tagged/slf4j) and use this API directly in all unrelated classes. First add this to your configuration:

```
akka {
    event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
    loglevel = "DEBUG"
}
```

Then choose some SLF4J implementation, I suggest [logback](/questions/tagged/logback). In your actors continue using `ActorLogging` trait. In other classes simply rely on SLF4J API - or even better - try out [slf4s](https://github.com/weiglewilczek/slf4s) facade around SLF4J.

Tip: try out the following logging pattern in Logback:

```
<pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} | %-5level | %thread | %X{akkaSource} | %logger{1} | %m%n%rEx</pattern>
```

The `%X{akkaSource}` will print actor path when available (just like standard logging).

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not entirely sure why ActorLogging exists, but since it does, does it matter that the method my actor is calling is would be using the SLF4J API directly instead of using Akka's logging event system?  Any dangers?  Alternatively, I could create a logging actor and just send log messages there.  What's preferred here?

Comment: But if you use SLF4J's factory directly, you do not get Async logging, right? I'm using dirty statics to access the System object atm :/

Comment: @AntonyStubbs: no, if you want to benefit from asynchronous logging, you would have to send a message to some actor - and use that actor to log the message...

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz right, which is what akka provides with it's logging actor framework (Slf4jEventHandler). I've settled on a solution, which is in my answer.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and when I saw this answer I was sure I found my solution, but it doesn't work! I've added to my `application.conf` the event-handlers line as described, in my case `"MyObject"` is instantiated with reflection, and inside of it logger is created by calling `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass.getName)` , and yet all the keys I placed in the MDC, all the %X places are empty /: could someone please share a golden advice?

Answer (score 19):

Using Akka 2.2.1, I was able to put this into my App to get logging outside of an actor:

```
import akka.event.Logging
val system = ActorSystem("HelloSystem", ConfigFactory.load.getConfig("akka"))
val log = Logging.getLogger(system, this)
log.info("Hi!")
```

This seems like a simpler solution for unifying an application's logging.

Comment: This answer does not solve the actual problem. You create an entire ActorSystem just to do some logging in a class. If you need it somewhere else are you going to create another ActorSystem? Might as well pass the reference of your first created ActorSystem around.

Comment: Not sure why this was heavily upvoted in light of the former comment. But I'd like to hope it's safe to pass your actor's logging function to the class, instead.

Answer (score 10):

As has been mentioned, you're spoiled for options for non-actor logging within an actor system. I am going to attempt to provide a set of heuristics to help you determine how you should route logging for your work.

1. **You can use a logger (log4j 1.x, logback, log4j 2.x) directly in both actor and non-actor code.**

   - This tightly couples your code to a logger implementation. This is fine if it's your code, not to be used elsewhere, but not fine if you're building a library or intend to open source your work.
   - If you do this, you gain no benefits from the actor system. Logging calls may become blocking calls, depending on how you have your logger set up, and thus this is frowned upon wherever performance or control over back pressure are important concerns.
   - Because actor code (along with services it can consume) can operate on many different threads, some traditional logging activities such as the use of a threadlocal MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Context) can result in bizarre race conditions and context swtiching with logs output from messages that pass from actor to actor. Activities such as swapping MDCs onto messages before sending them may become necessary to preserve context between actor and non actor code.
   - To capture ActorSystem events such as dead letters and supervision, you may need to write a logging adapter and specify it in your application.conf. These are pretty straightforward.
2. **You can use the SLF4J facade for both actor and non-actor logging.**

   - You are no longer coupled to a logger impl and what's more your services aren't coupled to akka. This is the best option for portability.
   - You may inherit blocking behavior from your log framework.
   - You may have to manage MDCs
   - To capture ActorSystem events you'll need to specify "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger" in your application.conf
   - You'll need to include an slf4j provider jar on the classpath to route slf4j log events to your chosen logger
3. **You can use Akka's Logging as your facade in both Actor and non-actor code**

   - You aren't coupled to a logger impl OR to slf4j, but you're coupled to a version of akka. This is probably a requirement of your system anyway, but for libraries it might reduce portability.
   - You have to pass around an actor system to act as the "bus" for loggers. Tight coupling to a working actor system reduces portability further. (Within an app I usually build a little LoggingViaActorSystem trait with an implicit or global ActorSystem, which makes it easier to deal with this in code but not across dependencies).
   - Non-blocking aynchronous logging is guaranteed, even if your logger doesn't support them. Causal consistency of logging is likely due to the use of a single consumer mailbox. However, memory safety and back pressure are not (I believe Akka logging uses an unbounded mailbox) --
   - There are options such as use of a  [DiagnosticLoggingAdapter](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/logging.html#MDC_values_defined_by_the_application) for avoiding the complexity of managing your own MDCs as work passes from actor to actor. Consistency should be preserved even as non-actor code mutates these MDCs.
   - Logging is not likely to be available during an out-of-memory crash, and is sensitive to thread starvation on the default dispatcher
   - You'll need to specify your chosen logger in application.conf unless you're interested in logging to standard out

You're welcome to mix and match the above behaviors as necessary to meet your requirements. For example, you might choose to bind to SLF4J for libraries and use Akka logging for everything else. Just note that mixing blocking and non-blocking logging could cause race conditions where causes (logged async via an actor) are logged after their effects (logged sync directly).

Comment: Does option 3 exclude simply passing the logger of the Akka actor using the non-actor class?

Answer (score 8):

I've now settled on simply passing my central logging system around through DI constructor injection (Guice). And in my classes that do logging regularly (where asynchronicity is important), I take the injected ActorSystem and call the

```
this.log = akka.event.Logging.getLogger(actorSystem, this);
```

in the classes constructor.

Comment: Another option, which you might like better for cases where you don't want to grow the object to hold such a reference, is to add a second parameter list `( implicit log:LoggingAdapter )` to methods that need to do logging.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [latest (currently version 2.6.9) logging documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/logging.html) using a Logger obtained from `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory` is perfectly fine, and is actually the **recommended** way to log outside an actor. I copy hereafter the exact wording.

> It’s perfectly fine to use a Logger retrieved via
> org.slf4j.LoggerFactory, but then the logging events will not include
> the akkaSource MDC value. **This is the recommend way when logging
> outside of an actor**, including logging from Future callbacks.

I also provide hereafter a snippet based on the example

```
val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.mypackage.MyObject")

Future {
  // do something
  "result"
}.onComplete {
  case Success(result) => log.info("Success!: {}", result)
  case Failure(exc)    => log.error("Failure!", exc)
}
```

In order to minimize performance penalties by logging one can configure an asynchronous appender for the SLF4J backend. Logback is the recommended logging backend.

```
dependencies {
  compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'
}
```

A starting point for configuration of logback.xml for production:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>myapp.log</file>
    <immediateFlush>false</immediateFlush>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>myapp_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>[%date{ISO8601}] [%level] [%logger] [%marker] [%thread] - %msg MDC: {%mdc}%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <queueSize>8192</queueSize>
    <neverBlock>true</neverBlock>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</appender>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC"/>
</root>
```

> Logging generally means IO and locks, which can slow down the
> operations of your code if it was performed synchronously.

The configurations shown above are the ones provided by the AKKA logging documentation. The documentation provides more information and can be found [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/logging.html#slf4j-backend)

Answer (score 0):

simply create your own logger:

```
private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(YourClass.getClass)
```