# Using Actor Logging Via SLF4j and logback vs using org.slf4j to log using SLF4J and logback

Tags: scala, logging, akka, logback, slf4j

I am confused with the best practice to use in logging. I found by reading that SLF4J removes the coupling between the application and logging API etc. So if i use actor logging, will it not be closely coupled to application?.I have also checked a lot of github codes and i noticed that they only use actor logging and not org.SLF4J.LoggerFactory logging. Why?

Some links which i referred

[SACHA'S BLOG OF PROGRAMMATICALNESS](https://sachabarbs.wordpress.com/2016/08/03/akka-logging/)

[Another Good read](https://dzone.com/articles/logging-java-switching-logback)

[stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157642/akka-logging-outside-actor) -> Checked the last answer

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we are in a new world, a world where we want to be reactive and non-blocking but some information before that.

Akka is using for logging SLF4j api that is a facade over common logging libraries i.e. log4j, logback, but does all of this async in order to not block actor.

So:

```
log.info("Received msg: {} use thread {} to dispatch", message, Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

in an actor where log is defined as:

```
LoggingAdapter log = Logging.getLogger(getContext().system(), this);
```

sends a logging message to logging actor, and the IO operations is actually done by this specialized actor.

Log4j or logback is only the implementation of actual logging, that's why you still need to configure one of if in your project.

```
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d,%p] [%X{sourceThread}] [%c{1}.%M:%L] %m%n
```

%X{sourceThread} actually gives you the execution thread where the logging message was issued by original actor and not the thread that executes the IO operation inside logging actor (logged by %t) - more on this http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/logging.html

My advice is to use log4j 2 since is using async operations and will not block the thread behind logging actor - more about log4j 2 performance on https://www.grobmeier.de/log4j-2-performance-close-to-insane-20072013.html

Comment: Thanks for that information on using of logging. My question was though we have SLF4j API which implements logging, why do we use akka logging and not SLF4j's inbuilt methods for logging?

Comment: Because as I explained, is desired to not block the actor with IO operations, for better performance of the actor and throughput, that's why is desired to use akka logging inside actor, and from there actual logging will be shipped by SLF4j.

Comment: Awesome!! Got it.Thank you