# Is this logging blocking?

Tags: scala, logging, akka, logback, slf4j

I have read that AkkaLogging is async and directly using slf4j is blocking. Consider the below code:

application.conf:

```
akka {
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
}
```

logback.xml:

```
<configuration>
<appender name="InfoFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
<file>Testing.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="INFO">
<appender-ref ref="InfoFile" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

Log statements:

```
  log.info("Sample logging")
```

Will this logging code be still blocking?If so, does it mean there is no way to achieve non blocking file logging in akka?

Comment: Please check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41262196/using-actor-logging-via-slf4j-and-logback-vs-using-org-slf4j-to-log-using-slf4j for some ,hopefully, useful info.

Answer (score 0):

Akka logging is asynchronous.
But from [this document](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/logging.html#slf4j-directly-java), it seems "logging operations will block while the underlying infrastructure writes the log statements".
However, you can use nonblocking appenders [AsyncAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#AsyncAppender) in your logback.xml to avoid this.